# Generating high order interaction terms within R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I wish to have a method to generate a list of all interaction terms for a generic set of variables up to a specified order. E.g. for variables x,y,z degree 3 I want code to list all interactions i.e. x, x*y, x^2 *y, x * y * z etc.

I figured this should be possible using the poly function (as this calculates all interaction terms in the way I describe above):

```
#specify a dataframe with the desired variables- in this case x,y and z
tmp <- data.frame(x=runif(4),y=runif(4),z=runif(4))
#use the poly function to generate all interaction terms (up to order 3 in this example)
res<-poly(as.matrix(tmp),degree=3)
#use the colnames function to extract the power of x,y,z in each term 
termOrder<-colnames(res)
```

Where I am stuck is I think it should be possible to then combine my variable names x,y,z with the powers given from the termOrder result. E.g. the first column which is 1.0.0 should map to x^1*y^0*z^0 = x and so on, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

1. Is there a more sensible approach to achieve this than using poly? I note that the multiplying out of the random numbers is a waste- I only want to generate a list of strings.
2. If this is a sensible approach can you please suggest a way to combine the termOrder result and my variable names.

Comment: In what form should the result be? Is this a list of formula terms?

Comment: Yes a list of formula terms would be ideal. I have updated the question for clarity.

Comment: Something like `with(mtcars, poly(mpg, wt, hp, degree = 3))`?

Comment: I think this is similar to my example, but neither give the result I need. In your example I would want the function call to be myFunction(names,3) where names is the list mpg,wt,hp and the function result is the list hp, hp^2, hp^3, wt, hp*wt.... etc etc as in my example above with x, y, z.

Comment: You should create one unified example. You have a descriptive example with no valid code with names x, y, z. And then you have a code example with no names. And I would get rid of the memory part - it seems unrelated. Ask another question about memory if you must, but the answer is going to be "don't ask for 1M terms if you don't have enough memory for them".

Comment: Ok. I have tried to reword. Does that help?